# Exc_Bad_Access on main function and unable to pass instance variables through classes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, exc-bad-access, init

**Updated post**

Now, I have a EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the main 2 times out of 7 and I don't know why the heightOfPumpView result is 0 from the pumpCustomView class when the result of pumpViewHeight is 607.

PumpViewController.m

```
#import "PumpViewController.h"
#import "PumpModel.h"
#import "PumpCustomView.h"

@implementation PumpViewController

@synthesize labels;
@synthesize heightOfPumpView;
- (id)init
{

if (self = [super init]) 
{
    labels = [[PumpModel alloc]init];

    PumpCustomView* pumpView = [PumpCustomView alloc];
    heightOfPumpView = [pumpView pumpViewHeight];
    [labels pumpCreateLabel:heightOfPumpView];
    labelsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[labels labelsGroup]];

    [labels release];

        if (labelsArray!=nil) 
        {
            [pumpView addSubview:[labelsArray objectAtIndex:2]];
        }



    [labelsArray release];
    [pumpView release];
}

return self;
}


-(void) dealloc
{
[super dealloc];

}

@end
```

PumpModel.m

```
#import "PumpModel.h"
#import "PumpViewController.h"
#import "PumpCustomView.h"

@implementation PumpModel
@synthesize labelsGroup;

-(id)init
{
self = [super init];
return self;
}

-(void)pumpCreateLabel:(float)pumpViewHeight
{
theNumberOfPump = 8;
PumpViewController* pumpViewControllerAlloc = [PumpViewController alloc];
labelsGroup = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i = 0;i < theNumberOfPump; i++) 
{
    int pumpViewHeight = [pumpViewControllerAlloc heightOfPumpView];
    int pumpViewWidthA = 259;

    int resultHeight = pumpViewHeight/theNumberOfPump;
    CGFloat resultWidth = pumpViewWidthA/2;
    positionChart[i] = resultHeight * i;        

    newLabel[i] = [[NSTextField alloc] init] ;

    [newLabel[i] setIntValue:i];

    newLabel[i].frame = CGRectMake(resultWidth, positionChart[i], 300, 100);
    newLabel[i].font= [NSFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12];
    newLabel[i].textColor= [NSColor blackColor];
    newLabel[i].backgroundColor= [NSColor whiteColor];

    [labelsGroup addObject:newLabel[i]];
    [newLabel[i] release];

    NSLog(@"%@ %d",[[labelsGroup objectAtIndex:i] stringValue],positionChart[i]);
}
[pumpViewControllerAlloc release];

}

-(void) dealloc
{    
[labelsGroup release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't send messages to the object before `[super init]`, e.g.:

```
- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) 
    {
        [self setNumberOfPump:8];
    }
    return self;
}
```

This is also true for:

```
-(id)initWithNumberOfPump:(int)numberOfPump
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        theNumberOfPump = numberOfPump;
        [self pumpCreateLabel];
    }
    return self ; 
}
```

Comment: I agree but even if I put it into the if function, it does the same thing as described before. I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the [self setNumberOfPump:8];

Comment: This time I get a exc_bad_access on the [self pumpCreateLabel] from the PumpModel file

Comment: have you seen my edit? have you fixed `initWithNumberOfPump:` as well?

Comment: Yes I did, but the problem stills there but this time on the [self pumpCreateLabel] from the PumpModel file

Comment: Just to make sure we're talking about the same thing - have you modified `PumpModel` as my second example suggests?

Comment: I've modified functions from both files.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a crash, post the backtrace of the crash.

Looking at your `setNumberOfPump:` method, it seems quite wrong.

- labels is allocated, then released, likely leaving the instance variable as a dangling reference that'll crash later
- `labelsArray` is leaked
- your `dealloc` doesn't release any memory

You should try running Build and Analyze on your code, fixing any errors.   The above issues combined with comments regarding the `init` patterns indicates that you should likely review the Objective-C documentation to gain a better understanding of both initialization and memory management patterns.

Comment: I've done the best I can to correct those problems. Now it compiles correctly 3 times out of 5. When it does not compile, it xcode throws a exc_bad_access on main. I tried to use NSZombie and Leak tools to fix it but nothing special happens. I've updated my post. Thanks for your help!